# Is there a notification code when cursor position changes in Edit Control MFC?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

Is there a notification code sent when the cursor position changes in an Edit Control MFC? I want to display the cursor (character) position for the user

Comment: RICHEDIT controls send [EN_SELCHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/en-selchange), if that helps at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no [`EN_...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bumper-edit-control-reference-notifications) notification sent by the Edit control itself when the caret position changes.

However, you can use [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) to register for [`EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/event-constants) notifications for your app's process ID and UI thread ID.

> EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE
>   0x800B
>
> An object has changed location, shape, or size. The system sends this event for the following user interface elements: **caret** and window objects. Server applications send this event for their accessible objects.

You can then have your callback function filter the notifications by checking if the provided `hwnd` is your Edit control and the provided `idObject` is [`OBJID_CARET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/object-identifiers).

> OBJID_CARET
>
> The text insertion bar (caret) in the window.

When detected, you can get the actual caret position by sending an [`EM_GETSEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-getsel) message to the Edit control.

> Gets the starting and ending character positions (in TCHARs) of the current selection in an edit control.

Or, if you are using the [`CEdit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cedit-class?view=vs-2019) class, use its [`GetSel()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cedit-class?view=vs-2019#getsel) method.

> Call this function to get the starting and ending character positions of the current selection (if any) in an edit control, using either the return value or the parameters.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it try.